# Hide without removing background image

Tags: css, background-image

Is there a way to hide the background image in CSS without removing it? For convenience, I'm using CSS to change whether or not it is displayed, and relying on a class to make it show. So, by default, it would be hidden, but the class would make it show. Because of this, the background image cannot be altered. What background properties can I use to achieve this? Changing the size to "0 0" actually made it 1px in the top left corner - not completely hidden. CSS3 solutions are accepted.

Answer (score 41):

Just met the same problem.
I use:

`background-size: 0 0;`

I think it's a little bit *friendlier* than using some huuuuge negative values for `background-position`.

Comment: To add to this, you can also unhide the background using background-size: auto

Answer (score 16):

You could try positioning the background image outside of the viewable area, like setting

`background-position: -9999px -9999px`

or something less drastic depending on the viewable area.

Answer (score 4):

Create a css attribute and use toggleClass:

```
.class {
  background-image: url(...);
}

.class.toggle {
 background-image: none;
}

$('.class').toggleClass('toggle');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `background-position` and just move it out of the view of the element.

```
element.class{
  background-position:-9999px;
}
```

or

```
element.class{
  background:transparent;
}
```

That second solution should work. I haven't tested it and I'm not sure if that qualifies as "removing it."

Answer (score 1):

`background-position: -9000 -9000` is best choice i think

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using javascript, you could use that to modify the properties. In the example I am posting below I am assuming you also have jQuery lib, if not a straight up DOM manipulation would also work. I am also calling the element you wish to toggle its background image input node. And finally this method uses cookies.

=>To hide

```
   setCookie(inputNode.name, $(inputNode).css("background-image"),1);
   $(inputNode).css("background-image", "url()");
```

=>To unhide

```
$(inputNode).css("background-image",getCookie(inputNode.name));
```

Where

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}



function getCookie(c_name)
   {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
     x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
     }
    }
```

This worked for me. Hope helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the background position answers are probably the best solutions, but I wanted to throw visibility into the mix. Setting `visible: hidden` will remove it from view but keep the structure in tact.

Comment: He's asking for just a background image solution. That would hide the entire element.

Comment: And? Without seeing his markup he may not have content in the element and this would be perfectly viable option.

Comment: "What background properties can I use to achieve this? " ... "hide the background image in CSS" It's quite clear he's looking for a purely background solution. This answer just isn't useful for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

One twist on retro web design is to use the classic `spacer.gif` to replace/hide your background image. Recall that [spacer.gif was used](http://www.windyweb.com/html_tips.htm) as a way to layout a grid system (with tables) back in the early (horrible) days of CSS. It is a one-pixel image with one transparent pixel.

You can use spacer.gif in the 21st century like this:

```
#ImageBox
{
    background: url(../images/my-regular-background.png) no-repeat center center;

    &.ImageLoaded
    {
        background-image: url(../images/spacer.gif);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the mix, you can place 2 images in the style property, and when you want to hide one, simply change the order of them in the property. This will meet the needs of not manipulating the image.

Your hider.gif can be a single pixel or a completely different image altogether.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
bg_hidden {
    background-image: url(hider.gif), url(realImage.jpg);

}
bg_shown {
    background-image: url(realImage.jpg), url(hider.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg_shown">
<button onclick="this.parent.className='bg_hidden'">Hide BG</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I haven't checked this code for bugs, so buyer beware ;-)